# Bootstrap footer menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I m expecting like [this](http://s21.postimg.org/699m1drg7/untitled.png) footer menu by using bootstrap classes

Here is basic bootstrap classes:

```
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

May i know, How to do make, footer menu by using bootstrap classes?

Thanks,

Comment: What have you tried so far that would make you expect the results you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general way is to make use of the grid system of bootstrap.

```
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <!-- other tags go here -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <!-- other tags go here -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <!-- other tags go here -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <!-- other tags go here -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

You can add as many `.row` divs as you require, but for each `.row` div, the sum of numbers at the end of `.col-md-3` divs has to be equal or less than 12.

col stands for column and md stands for medium screen size. Other screen sizes available are xs (extra small), sm (small) and lg (large). So you can have .col-lg-3 or .col-xs-6 or anything you prefer as long as the sum of the numbers is no greater than 12. You can also have different classes for screen-sizes in the same tag. For example,

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">...</div>
```

There are also other features like offsetting or nesting or ordering the columns, etc. For a complete guide, check out [getbootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)